Creating an array of string pointers
I've reviewed many of the previous entries for this, but can't figure out why my (seemingly simple) construct doesn't work:
I want to create an array of pointers to previously-defined strings (char *). Here's my
construct:
const char *gs_Floatx0_FMT  = "%c%4.0f %4.0f %4.0f %4.0f";
const char *gs_Floatx1_FMT  = "%c%4.1f %4.1f %4.1f %4.1f";
const char *gs_Floatx2_FMT  = "%c%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f %4.2f";
const char *gs_Floatx3_FMT  = "%c%4.3f%4.3f%4.3f%4.3f";
const char *gsa_Fmt_Tbl[]   = {
    gs_Floatx0_FMT, gs_Floatx1_FMT,
    gs_Floatx2_FMT, gs_Floatx3_FMT};

The error I get is "main.c:40:15: error: (188) constant expression required"
Each FMT is a constant char pointer. Therefore, doesn't const char *gsa_Fmt_Tbl[] create an array of char pointers?

Ohhhh ... my bad. Sorry

@MikeTheButcher, "Each FMT is a constant char pointer." --> No, nor are they constant expressions.  Each is a const char pointer.  Not the same thing.

It seems like you're doing an extra/unnecessary level of indirection.
What about:
const char *gsa_Fmt_Tbl[] = {
    "%c%4.0f %4.0f %4.0f %4.0f",
    "%c%4.1f %4.1f %4.1f %4.1f",
    "%c%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f %4.2f",
    "%c%4.3f%4.3f%4.3f%4.3f"
};


gs_Floatx0_FM ... are not constant expressions in C language understanding. const variables are not constant expressions.
You can change it to:
const char gs_Floatx0_FMT[]  = "%c%4.0f %4.0f %4.0f %4.0f";
const char gs_Floatx1_FMT[]  = "%c%4.1f %4.1f %4.1f %4.1f";
const char gs_Floatx2_FMT[]  = "%c%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f %4.2f";
const char gs_Floatx3_FMT[]  = "%c%4.3f%4.3f%4.3f%4.3f";
const char *gsa_Fmt_Tbl[]   = {
    gs_Floatx0_FMT, gs_Floatx1_FMT,
    gs_Floatx2_FMT, gs_Floatx3_FMT};

And it will compile fine as address of static storage duration object is the constant expression

6.6 Constant Expressions


6.6p4: Address Constants

An address constant is a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration, or to a function designator. The
value of an address constant may be added to or subtracted from an
integer constant expression to form a constant expression.

This means the address of variables or functions with static storage
duration (like global variables or static objects) qualifies as a
constant expression.
6.6p6: Evaluation at Translation
Each constant expression shall evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable values for its type.


ohhhhh my bad. Sorry, I tested in godbolt with your code instead of the OPs code.

I of course  retracted the DW

Now good in MSVC too.

In your answer, you wrote: "const variables are not constant expressions" -- As far as I can tell, this statement is incorrect. §6.6 ¶14 of the ISO C23 standard allows compilers to also accept other types of expressions as constant expressions. As I have shown in my answer, both GCC and Clang do accept const variables as constant expressions.

@AndreasWenzel I will be focusing on C23 when it is more broadly implemented in compilers

@0____: This is not something that is new to ISO C23. §6.6 ¶10 of the ISO C11 standard states something very similar.

Where is the quoted text in this answer from?

@AndreasWenzel The only thing C23 changed afaik is support for constexpr which doesn't apply here. The awful wording in 6.6 is still there: "An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions; however, it is implementationdefined
whether they are an integer constant expression." Essentially giving questionable implementations a chance to "wing it". Compilers like gcc and clang have taken strange liberties based on this - arguable neither compiler is conforming and neither is strictly conforming for sure. gcc had a more traditional interpretation of this earlier.

Your posted code will work when written inside a function, because in that case, the variables that you declare will have automatic storage duration.
However, when declaring these variables outside a function, those variables will have static storage duration. This means that according §6.7.11 ¶5 of the ISO C23 standard, all expressions in the initializer must be constant expressions or string literals. This rule makes sense, because variables with static storage duration are initialized before program startup. That is why they must be initialized to some constant value.
In the declaration
const char *gsa_Fmt_Tbl[]   = {
    gs_Floatx0_FMT, gs_Floatx1_FMT,
    gs_Floatx2_FMT, gs_Floatx3_FMT};

the expressions gs_Floatx0_FMT, gs_Floatx1_FMT, gs_Floatx2_FMT and gs_Floatx3_FMT are not constant expressions.
It would not make sense to consider gs_Floatx0_FMT, gs_Floatx1_FMT, gs_Floatx2_FMT and gs_Floatx3_FMT as constant expressions, because they are not even declared as const. Only the data type to which they point is declared as const.
You can change the pointers to const by changing their declarations to the following:
const char *const gs_Floatx0_FMT  = "%c%4.0f %4.0f %4.0f %4.0f";
const char *const gs_Floatx1_FMT  = "%c%4.1f %4.1f %4.1f %4.1f";
const char *const gs_Floatx2_FMT  = "%c%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f %4.2f";
const char *const gs_Floatx3_FMT  = "%c%4.3f %4.3f %4.3f %4.3f";

That way, the compilers GCC and Clang will accept the expressions gs_Floatx0_FMT, gs_Floatx1_FMT, gs_Floatx2_FMT and gs_Floatx3_FMT as constant expressions, and your posted code will work.
However, not all ISO C compliant compilers will accept these expressions as constant expressions, because they are not required to do so. For example, the MSVC compiler will not do so. §6.6 of the ISO C23 standard only requires that a compiler accepts certain types of expressions as constant expressions, and an object that is declared as const is not one of them. But, §6.6 ¶14 allows compilers to accept also other types of expressions as constant expressions, which the compilers GCC and Clang are doing here.
If you want a solution that is guaranteed to work on all ISO C compliant compilers, then you will have to change your code to something different, as shown in the other answers.

The main problem isn't really that gcc and clang allow implementation-defined constant expression. But it is a huge problem that they allow them under strict mode -pedantic, even though it is 100% implementation-defined behavior. This is forcing all gcc users who need to be compatible with conforming C compilers to stick to gcc version 7 somewhere. (Which one might want to do anyway since gcc is a veritable bug fest from there on...)
